# How to bypass Signature verification in Android APK while decompiling and recompiling

Tags: android, apk, apktool

Hi I am trying to decompile and recompile an Android Ap from this link https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.telepacket.TpSmart I am not doing any changes Just decompiled and recompiled it with APKTOOL after recompiling I signed it with Keytool. Problem here is when install this recompiled app on launch it will ask Operator code (you can enter 2020 as operator code) then press on submit It is giving a dialog messsage "Please update app to latest version" though app is the latest version. I think developer has used some signature verification. Please any one tell me how to bypass it?

Comment: increase  your app version number in gradle file

Comment: brother its a decompiled apk not an Android Studio project. and version of decompiled apk and one in PlayStore are same.

Comment: like @sasikumar said, try to increase app version number. There's app version check on server side.

Comment: I am decompiling latest version of that apk. So version number will be same as it has in PlayStore. Then what is the point in changing version number